# SLD style definition from GeoServer to Drupal

Tags: geoserver, sld, style, drupal, curl

I've been experimenting with the SLD style definitions in both GeoServer and Drupal. What I want to achieve is to create a new style in GeoServer (by a curl operation, but I know how that works) and sync that style to Drupal's GeoServer Structure.

In the GeoServer itself, the styling applies perfectly when going to the Layer Preview. Also adding a new style in Drupal will sync itself to the GeoServer, BUT not the other way around...

So basically my question: Is it possible to sync a GeoServer style to Drupal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can any one help me on this please?